# Simple PRNG algorithm has different Python/C output - integer overflow differences?

Tags: python, c, algorithm, prng

**Edit:** As it turns out, I typoed the seed value in my test code in the C version (It wasn't the same as I pasted in this question), so I was getting different output. Thanks everyone.

I need to generate psuedo random numbers in a C program, and then pass the seed to a Python program later and generate the same numbers.

PRNGs are something that I consider over my head, so I looked up an implemention (in C):

```
static unsigned long next = 1;

/* RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767 */
int myrand(void) {
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return((unsigned)(next/65536) % 32768);
}
```

And a *naive* port:

```
next = 1

def myrand():
    global next
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345
    return (next / 65536) % 32768
```

However, these both produce different values. I'm guessing `next` in the C implementation overflows, and that's why the two functions produce different values. But in Python numbers have no explicit type, they don't overflow, and they're not unsigned. How can I replicate this behavior in Python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Overwriting the name `next` is indeed very naive.

Comment: I think it's because in C the decimal values are truncated and in python they aren't

Comment: Built in python numbers do have an explicit type.  They just behave sanely because it's a more modern language.  Could you provide the first few numbers generated from your C code/platform in your question?

Comment: @wim Using a seed of 5, and 3 iterations: 16838, 5758, 10113 (on Linux, if that matters). By "they don't have an explicit type", I meant that Python doesn't have multiple explicit integer types for 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, etc, it simply uses more memory as needed to store numbers of infinite* size

Comment: Beware that in newer versions of python (3+), integer division only happens when you explicitly ask for it. To get this behavior, use `//` instead of `/`.

Comment: @Salis I'm on linux too. I tried compiling the C version with GCC and running the python one on python 2.7 and they work the same for me. On the first 3 iterations I get the same as you. Can you put an example of when they start giving different values?

Comment: @Topo: Even if it works as-is, some bounds control on `next` is needed.  Otherwise `next` becomes arbitrarily large, and as a result dealing with it becomes arbitrarily slow.

Comment: @Topo As it turns out, I'm a clown and typoed the seed. Wow. Thanks everyone

Comment: Yeah your comment has the results for seed 1 not seed 5 ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking every computation modulo (%) 2^32 (assuming 32 bit integer width) should work.

```
next = 1
modulo = 2**32
def myrand():
    global next
    next = ((next * 1103515245) + 12345) % modulo
    return (next / 65536) % 32768
```

Comment: +1 but I think the modulus should be 2^32. After all, 2^32 - 1 is a valid value for such an int, and it wraps around only at 2^32.

Comment: and make sure to do 2**32 because in python 2^32 is something else entirely

Comment: -1  the modulo doesn't actually do anything.  run it without and you will get the same result.  also don't encourage the use of global.

Comment: @wim: The modulo may not change the result but its usage is well-warranted here. Consider what happens without it -- `next` becomes arbitrarily large and slow.

Comment: @wim You are correct, I should probably have checked that first. I assumed it was overflow too.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use a global variable here, the problem is more suited to a generator function.  Also you certainly don't want to use `next` as a variable name in python because it shadows a very useful builtin name (actually I'm using it below!)

```
def myrand(seed=1):
    n = seed
    while True:
      n = n * 1103515245 + 12345
      yield (n // 65536) % 32768


g = myrand()
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
```

This works for me on python3, apparently no overflow handling needn't, and matches your first 3 inputs.  Could you post a few more so we can see where/why they may diverge?

Comment: @Topo As it turns out, I'm a clown and typoed the seed in the C version. How embarrassing. For the record, the global variable, overwriting, etc was just for a brief question, not actual code.

Answer (score 0):

```
next = 1
def myrand():
    global next
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345
    return (next & 0xFFFFFFFF / 65536) % 32768
```

Comment: You'll need to make this answer more substantive for it to meet SO quality standards.